# suggestionbox doesn't display list

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Found strange problem.
the suggestionBox doesn't display the list received from the suggestionAction method, however I tested the returned list and i'ts not empty. the empty suggestion box is displayed until the list becomes empty and the message of the nothingLabel="" property is displayed.
heres the jsp code

```
                <h:panelGroup id="Parent_ProjectRef_Parent">
                    <h:inputText id="Parent_ProjectRef" tabindex="4"
                        alt="validatorBean.fld['companyName']"

                        disabled="#{not groupedProjectCreationBean.parentProjectRequired}"
                        value="#{groupedProjectCreationBean.groupedProject.parentProjectCode}"
                        required="#{groupedProjectCreationBean.parentProjectRequired}"
                        requiredMessage="à remplacer par ValidatorBean">
                        <a4j:support status="null" event="onblur" ajaxSingle="true"
                            reRender="Parent_ProjectRef_Parent" />
                        <f:converter converterId="byblos.converter.parent.grpd.proj.ref" />
                        <f:validator validatorId="byblos.validator.parent.grpd.proj.ref"></f:validator>
                    </h:inputText>

                    <rich:suggestionbox id="parentProjectSuggestionBox" status="null"
                        for="Parent_ProjectRef" rules="none" ajaxSingle="true"
                        suggestionAction="#{groupedProjectCreationBean.fetchParentProject}"
                        selfRendered="true"
                        var="result" nothingLabel="aucune valeur disponible"
                        fetchValue="#{result.parentProjectCode}"
                        first="0" minChars="0" shadowOpacity="1" shadowDepth="1"
                        cellpadding="0" usingSuggestObjects="true">

                        <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onselect" status="null">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener 
                                value="#{result.idr}"
                                target="#{groupedProjectCreationBean.groupedProject.parentProjectId}" />
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                value="#{result.parentProjectCoder}"
                                target="#{groupedProjectCreationBean.groupedProject.parentProjectCode}" />
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener 
                                value="#{result.parentProjectLabelr}" 
                                target="#{groupedProjectCreationBean.groupedProject.parentProjectLabel}"/>
                        </a4j:support>

                        <h:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{result.parentProjectCode}" />
                        </h:column>
                    </rich:suggestionbox>
                    <a4j:log hotkey="Q" level="ALL" popup="true" ></a4j:log>

                </h:panelGroup>
```

and here is the suggestaction

```
public List<GroupedProjectDTO> fetchParentProject(Object suggest) {
        String pref = (String) suggest;
        result = new ArrayList<GroupedProjectDTO>();
    try {

        result = projectService.fetchgroupedProjectReferences(pref, null);
        for(GroupedProjectDTO gp:result){
            System.out.println(gp.getProjectCode());
        }
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++");
    } catch (ByblosException e) {

        System.out.println(e.toString());
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and I almost forgot a4j:log

```
   debug[15:24:09,118]: Queue is empty now
debug[15:24:09,118]: New request added to queue 'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox'. Queue similarityGroupingId changed to tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox
debug[15:24:09,118]: Queue will wait 0ms before submit
debug[15:24:09,118]: Queue 'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox' will submit request NOW
debug[15:24:09,119]: NEW AJAX REQUEST !!! with form: tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm
debug[15:24:09,119]: Start XmlHttpRequest
debug[15:24:09,120]: Request state : 1
debug[15:24:09,122]: QueryString: AJAXREQUEST=tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_20pc6&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm=tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AProjectRef=SP-1234&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AParent_ProjectRef=p1234&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AparentProjectSuggestionBox_selection=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AnomProj=rfgerg&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AdateDebutInputDate=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AdateDebutInputCurrentDate=07%2F2013&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3ArespProj=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AdateFinInputDate=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AdateFinInputCurrentDate=07%2F2013&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Abudget=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aduree=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AnbreIntervenants=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AtypePrestation_parent%3A0%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_67pc6=7&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AtypePrestation_parent%3A0%3AinputRate=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aclient=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AactivitySect=2&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AbusinessUnit=5&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3ArespProjClt=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AdateDebutCltInputDate=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AdateDebutCltInputCurrentDate=07%2F2013&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AbudgetClt=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AdateFinCltInputDate=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AdateFinCltInputCurrentDate=07%2F2013&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AnbreIntervenantsClt=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AdureeClt=&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_152pc6=ezrgrezgezgrezgreg&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_12pc6=tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_13pc6&javax.faces.ViewState=9148198507343241650%3A1531803180393478251&ajaxSingle=tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AparentProjectSuggestionBox&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AparentProjectSuggestionBox=tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AparentProjectSuggestionBox&inputvalue=p1234&inputvaluerequest=null&AJAX%3AEVENTS_COUNT=1&
debug[15:24:09,124]: Request state : 1
debug[15:24:09,393]: Request state : 2
debug[15:24:09,393]: Request state : 3
debug[15:24:09,394]: Request state : 4
debug[15:24:09,394]: Request end with state 4
debug[15:24:09,394]: Response with content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
debug[15:24:09,394]: Full response content: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr"><head></head><body><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:suggest" class="rich-sb-int-decor-table "><colgroup span="1"></colgroup><tbody><tr class="rich-sb-int richfaces_suggestionEntry "><td nowrap="nowrap" class="rich-sb-cell-padding" style="padding: 0px;"></td></tr><tr id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:0NothingLabel" class="rich-sb-int " style="display: none;"><td nowrap="nowrap" class="rich-sb-cell-padding" style="padding: 0px;">aucune valeur disponible</td></tr></tbody></table><meta name="Ajax-Update-Ids" content="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:suggest" /><span id="ajax-view-state"><input autocomplete="off" id="javax.faces.ViewState" name="javax.faces.ViewState" type="hidden" value="9148198507343241650:-7433138755089562496" /></span><meta id="Ajax-Response" name="Ajax-Response" content="true" /><span id="_ajax:data"> {'suggestionObjects':[{'budget':null,'budgetClt':null,'competences':null,'connectedUser':null,'contactsId':null,'contexteProjet':null,'creator':null,'customerId':null,'customerLabel':null,'dateCreation':null,'dateDebut':null,'dateDebutClt':null,'dateFin':null,'dateFinClt':null,'dateModification':null,'domaineFonctionnel':null,'elementsReussite':null,'enjeuxProjet':null,'environnementTechnique':null,'id':106,'intervenants':null,'isClosed':null,'isModified':null,'label':'Homologation','livrables':null,'methodeUtilisee':null,'nbreIntervenants':null,'nbreIntervenantsClt':null,'nomCreateur':null,'nomModif':null,'objectifsProjet':null,'organisation':null,'organistaionProjetClt':null,'parentProjectCode':null,'parentprojectId':null,'parentprojectLabel':null,'prenomCreateur':null,'prenomModif':null,'projectCode':'P123456','responsabilitesActivites':null,'responsableProjet':null,'responsableProjetClt':null,'rexTalan':null,'rowIndex':null,'societeId':null,'syntheseIntervention':null,'syntheseProjet':null,'typePrestationsIds':null,'valAjoutee':null} ] ,'requestedObjects':{} } </span></body></html>
debug[15:24:09,394]: Header Ajax-Expired not found, search in <meta>
debug[15:24:09,394]: search for elements by name 'meta' in element #document
debug[15:24:09,394]: Find <meta name='Ajax-Update-Ids' content='tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:suggest'>
debug[15:24:09,395]: Find <meta name='Ajax-Response' content='true'>
debug[15:24:09,395]: Header Ajax-Update-Ids not found, search in <meta>
debug[15:24:09,395]: search for elements by name 'meta' in element #document
debug[15:24:09,395]: Find <meta name='Ajax-Update-Ids' content='tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:suggest'>
debug[15:24:09,395]: Update page by list of rendered areas from response tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:suggest
debug[15:24:09,395]: search for elements by name 'script' in element #document
debug[15:24:09,395]: search for elements by name 'link' in element #document
debug[15:24:09,396]: call getElementById for id= org.ajax4jsf.queue_script
debug[15:24:09,396]: Update page part from call parameter for ID tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:suggest
debug[15:24:09,396]: call getElementById for id= tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:suggest
debug[15:24:09,396]: Replace content of node by outerHTML()
debug[15:24:09,397]: search for elements by name 'script' in element table
debug[15:24:09,397]: Scripts in updated part count : 0
debug[15:24:09,397]: call getElementById for id= org.ajax4jsf.oncomplete
debug[15:24:09,397]: Call local oncomplete function after processing updates
debug[15:24:09,398]: After request: queue 'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox'
debug[15:24:09,398]: There are 0 requests more in this queue
debug[15:24:09,398]: Queue is empty now
debug[15:24:09,398]: Update part of page for Id: tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:suggest successful
debug[15:24:09,398]: call getElementById for id= ajax-view-state
debug[15:24:09,398]: Hidden JSF state fields: [object HTMLSpanElement]
debug[15:24:09,398]: Namespace for hidden view-state input fields is undefined
debug[15:24:09,398]: search for elements by name 'input' in element span
debug[15:24:09,399]: Replace value for inputs: 111 by new values: 1
debug[15:24:09,399]: Input in response: javax.faces.ViewState
debug[15:24:09,399]: Found same input on page with type: hidden
debug[15:24:09,401]: search for elements by name 'INPUT' in element span
debug[15:24:09,401]: Replace value for inputs: 111 by new values: 0
debug[15:24:09,401]: call getElementById for id= _A4J.AJAX.focus
debug[15:24:09,401]: No focus information in response
debug[15:24:09,402]: call getElementById for id= _ajax:data
debug[15:24:09,402]: AJAX response complete - updateChoices
debug[15:24:09,405]: render for index 0 and old index -1
debug[15:24:09,407]: Choices updated
debug[15:24:40,369]: set timeout for request suggestion
debug[15:24:40,662]: Have Event [object Object] with properties: target: [object HTMLInputElement], srcElement: undefined, type: blur
debug[15:24:40,662]: Query preparation for form 'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm' requested
debug[15:24:40,662]: Append hidden control tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm with value [tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm] and value attribute [tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm]
debug[15:24:40,662]: Append text control tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:ProjectRef with value [SP-1234] and value attribute [SP-1234]
debug[15:24:40,662]: Append hidden control tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox_selection with value [] and value attribute [null]
```

tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:typePrestation_parent:0:j_id_jsp_471245161_67pc6 with value [7] and value attribute [null]

```
debug[15:24:40,665]: Append text control tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:nbreIntervenantsClt with value [] and value attribute [null]
debug[15:24:40,665]: Append text control tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:dureeClt with value [] and value attribute [null]
debug[15:24:40,665]: Append textarea control tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_152pc6 with value [ezrgrezgezgrezgreg] and value attribute [null]
debug[15:24:40,665]: Append hidden control tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_12pc6 with value [tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_13pc6] and value attribute [tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_13pc6]
debug[15:24:40,665]: Append hidden control javax.faces.ViewState with value [9148198507343241650:-7433138755089562496] and value attribute [9148198507343241650:-7433138755089562496]
debug[15:24:40,666]: Append text control tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef with value [p1234] and value attribute []
debug[15:24:40,666]: parameter tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_23pc6 with value tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_23pc6
debug[15:24:40,666]: parameter ajaxSingle with value tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef
debug[15:24:40,666]: Look up queue with default name
debug[15:24:40,666]: NEW AJAX REQUEST !!! with form: tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm
debug[15:24:40,666]: Start XmlHttpRequest
debug[15:24:40,667]: Request state : 1
debug[15:24:40,667]: QueryString: AJAXREQUEST=tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_20pc6&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm=tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_152pc6=ezrgrezgezgrezgreg&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_12pc6=tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_13pc6&javax.faces.ViewState=9148198507343241650%3A-7433138755089562496&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AParent_ProjectRef=p1234&tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_23pc6=tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3Aj_id_jsp_471245161_23pc6&ajaxSingle=tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm%3AParent_ProjectRef&
debug[15:24:40,668]: Request state : 1
debug[15:24:41,048]: Observer event occurs
debug[15:24:41,048]: Call data for update choices
debug[15:24:41,049]: Request state : 2
debug[15:24:41,050]: Request state : 3
debug[15:24:41,051]: Request state : 4
debug[15:24:41,051]: Request end with state 4
debug[15:24:41,051]: Response with content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
debug[15:24:41,051]: Full response content: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" /> <title>BYBLOS V</title> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/byblos/resources/images/logoTalanMini.ico" /> <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/byblos/resources/images/logoTalanMini.ico" /> <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/byblos/resources/css/admin.css" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/byblos/resources/css/newStyle.css" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/byblos/resources/css/form-elements.css" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="/byblos/js/behaviour.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> var conf = true; function resetConf() { conf = false; } window.history.forward(); </script> </head> <body> <span id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_Parent"><input id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef" type="text" name="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef" value="p1234" alt="validatorBean.fld['companyName']" onblur="A4J.AJAX.Submit('tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm',event,{'control':this,'status':'null','similarityGroupingId':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_23pc6','parameters':{'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_23pc6':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_23pc6','ajaxSingle':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef'} ,'containerId':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_20pc6'} )" style="border: 1px solid #CC3300;background:#F9E5E6 !important;" tabindex="4" /><div id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox" class="rich-sb-common-container " style="display:none; z-index: 201;width:200px;height:200px;;;"><div class="rich-sb-ext-decor-1"><div class="rich-sb-ext-decor-2" style=";; border-width: null null null null ;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="rich-sb-ext-decor-3"><tbody><tr><td><div class="_suggestion_size_ rich-sb-overflow" style="width:196px;height:196px;"><table width="100%" id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:suggest" border="0" cellpadding="0" rules="none"><tbody></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="rich-sb-shadow" style="opacity:0.1; filter:alpha(opacity=10);top: 1px; left: 1px; "></div></div><div id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox_script" style="display:none;"><script type="text/javascript">Richfaces.onAvailable('tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef', function() { new RichFaces.Suggestion('tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm','tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef','tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox',{'onselect':function(suggestion,event){A4J.AJAX.Submit('tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm',event,{'status':'null','similarityGroupingId':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:j_id_jsp_471245161_25pc6','parameters':{'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:j_id_jsp_471245161_25pc6':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:j_id_jsp_471245161_25pc6','ajaxSingle':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox'} ,'containerId':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_20pc6'} )},'implicitEventsQueue':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox','usingSuggestObjects':true,'status':'null','similarityGroupingId':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox','parameters':{'ajaxSingle':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox','tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox'} ,'containerId':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_20pc6'} ); });</script></div><iframe src="/byblos/a4j/g/3_3_2.SR1org/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/spacer.gif" id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox_iframe" style="position:absolute;display:none;z-index:200;"></iframe><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox_selection" name="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox_selection" /><script id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_28pc6" type="text/javascript">LOG.registerPopup('Q','LogWindow',800,600,LOG.DEBUG);</script><span class="rich-tool-tip " id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_tooltip" style="z-index:99; "><span id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_tooltipcontent">La valeur du champ doit être conforme au format suivant: PXXXXXX</span><span id="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_tooltipscript" style="display:none"><script type="text/javascript" id="scripttabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_tooltip"> new ToolTip("tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_tooltip","tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef",{'showEvent':'mouseover'} ); </script></span></span></span><meta name="Ajax-Update-Ids" content="tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_Parent" /><span id="ajax-view-state"><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="9148198507343241650:-5046771196566875879" autocomplete="off" /></span><meta id="Ajax-Response" name="Ajax-Response" content="true" /> </body></html>
debug[15:24:41,051]: Header Ajax-Expired not found, search in <meta>
debug[15:24:41,051]: search for elements by name 'meta' in element #document
debug[15:24:41,052]: Find <meta name='null' content='IE=EmulateIE8'>
debug[15:24:41,052]: Find <meta name='null' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
debug[15:24:41,052]: Find <meta name='null' content='no'>
debug[15:24:41,052]: Find <meta name='Ajax-Update-Ids' content='tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_Parent'>
debug[15:24:41,052]: Find <meta name='Ajax-Response' content='true'>
debug[15:24:41,052]: Header Ajax-Update-Ids not found, search in <meta>
debug[15:24:41,052]: search for elements by name 'meta' in element #document
debug[15:24:41,052]: Find <meta name='null' content='IE=EmulateIE8'>
debug[15:24:41,052]: Find <meta name='null' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
debug[15:24:41,053]: Find <meta name='null' content='no'>
debug[15:24:41,053]: Find <meta name='Ajax-Update-Ids' content='tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_Parent'>
debug[15:24:41,053]: Update page by list of rendered areas from response tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_Parent
debug[15:24:41,053]: search for elements by name 'script' in element #document
debug[15:24:41,053]: <script> in response with src=/byblos/js/behaviour.js
debug[15:24:41,053]: Such element exist in document
debug[15:24:41,053]: search for elements by name 'link' in element #document
debug[15:24:41,054]: <link> in response with src=/byblos/resources/images/logoTalanMini.ico
debug[15:24:41,054]: Such element exist in document
debug[15:24:41,054]: <link> in response with src=/byblos/resources/images/logoTalanMini.ico
debug[15:24:41,055]: Such element exist in document
debug[15:24:41,056]: <link> in response with src=/byblos/resources/css/admin.css
debug[15:24:41,056]: Such element exist in document
debug[15:24:41,056]: <link> in response with src=/byblos/resources/css/newStyle.css
debug[15:24:41,056]: Such element exist in document
debug[15:24:41,056]: <link> in response with src=/byblos/resources/css/form-elements.css
debug[15:24:41,056]: Such element exist in document
debug[15:24:41,056]: call getElementById for id= org.ajax4jsf.queue_script
debug[15:24:41,057]: Update page part from call parameter for ID tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_Parent
debug[15:24:41,057]: call getElementById for id= tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_Parent
debug[15:24:41,058]: Replace content of node by outerHTML()
debug[15:24:41,064]: search for elements by name 'script' in element span
debug[15:24:41,065]: Scripts in updated part count : 3
debug[15:24:41,065]: Update part of page for Id: tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_Parent successful
debug[15:24:41,065]: call getElementById for id= ajax-view-state
debug[15:24:41,065]: Hidden JSF state fields: [object HTMLSpanElement]
debug[15:24:41,065]: Namespace for hidden view-state input fields is undefined
debug[15:24:41,065]: search for elements by name 'input' in element span
debug[15:24:41,065]: Replace value for inputs: 111 by new values: 1
debug[15:24:41,066]: Input in response: javax.faces.ViewState
debug[15:24:41,066]: Found same input on page with type: hidden
debug[15:24:41,068]: search for elements by name 'INPUT' in element span
debug[15:24:41,068]: Replace value for inputs: 111 by new values: 0
debug[15:24:41,068]: call getElementById for id= _A4J.AJAX.focus
debug[15:24:41,068]: No focus information in response
debug[15:24:41,117]: Evaluate script replaced area in document: Richfaces.onAvailable('tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef', function() { new RichFaces.Suggestion('tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm','tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef','tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox',{'onselect':function(suggestion,event){A4J.AJAX.Submit('tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm',event,{'status':'null','similarityGroupingId':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:j_id_jsp_471245161_25pc6','parameters':{'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:j_id_jsp_471245161_25pc6':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox:j_id_jsp_471245161_25pc6','ajaxSingle':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox'} ,'containerId':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_20pc6'} )},'implicitEventsQueue':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox','usingSuggestObjects':true,'status':'null','similarityGroupingId':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox','parameters':{'ajaxSingle':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox','tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:parentProjectSuggestionBox'} ,'containerId':'tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:j_id_jsp_471245161_20pc6'} ); });
debug[15:24:41,119]: Script evaluation succeeded
debug[15:24:41,119]: Evaluate script replaced area in document: LOG.registerPopup('Q','LogWindow',800,600,LOG.DEBUG);
debug[15:24:41,119]: Script evaluation succeeded
debug[15:24:41,119]: Evaluate script replaced area in document: new ToolTip("tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef_tooltip","tabPanelAndButtonsBarGrpdProjForm:Parent_ProjectRef",{'showEvent':'mouseover'} );
debug[15:24:41,123]: Script evaluation succeeded
debug[15:24:41,123]: call getElementById for id= org.ajax4jsf.oncomplete
debug[15:24:41,123]: Processing updates finished, no oncomplete function to call
```

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

there is no bug, I was using the wrong property for the display

```
<h:column>
     <h:outputText value="#{result.parentProjectCode}" />
</h:column>
```

instead of

```
<h:column>
     <h:outputText value="#{result.projectCode}" />
</h:column>
```